# Distribute work minimizing

Tags: assignment-problem

You have `n` types work items. Each work item must be distributed to at least `m` processors. There are k processors (n > k > m) available. You want to distribute work as fairly as possible.

Finally, you want to minimize the number of repeating pairs of work items across processors. I don't know how to express it well, need to use an example. Let's say that processor 1 has work items 2 and 3. Ideally no other processor would have that pair - so if another processor has work item 2, it won't have number 3. If it's not possible to avoid repeating, minimize the repetition (of course across all combos).

Comment: Let $W$ be the set of the work items. Then, we want to minimize $\min_{W_c \subseteq W} \{ n(W_c) \}$, where $W_c$ is any subset of $W$ and $n(W_c)$ is the number of processors that have exactly $W_c$ assigned to them. Is that the optimization function you want to minimize?

Comment: I think that's the correct definition.